# IIS wordpress ajax request failing

Tags: ajax, wordpress, iis, xmlhttprequest

We developed a website on a linux server. Everything is working on it, but when we migrate it to the production IIS server some ajax request began to fail.

If you try the url's independently on the browser, the url works, but on ajax request i receive an error even though the status of the request is 200.

You can see the requests working on the home carousel of the development version 
http://ismapps.net/frisbysite/

And see it fail the production version
http://www.frisby.com.co/

Here's one of the urls working properly
http://www.frisby.com.co/menu/frisdelicias/frisbandeja/?ajax=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making ajax calls from your production server to your development server which is causing violation of same origin policy.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ismapps.net/frisbysite/wp-content/themes/handcrafted/get-thumbnail.p…1389,2099,1391,1400,1393,1394,1395,1401,1397,1398,1399,2070,2072,2074,2073,. Origin http://www.frisby.com.co is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

You'll have to change the url of the ajax request to the production url, or add cross origin resource sharing headers to the development server if are actually suppose to be using that url.